# Semantic Proof of Tarski's Undefinability of Arithmetic Truth

Tags: logic, model-theory

A few years ago I took a logic course and I've since lost my notes.  I seem to remember a very semantic proof of Tarski's theorem on the undefinability of arithmetic truth, one that didn't use the diagonalization lemma or Godel numbering.  If my memory serves it was almost totally model-theoretic.  The wikipedia page mentions a semantic proof using Post's theorem but I'm fairly confident that wasn't used in the course.  It's very possible that I'm just misremembering but I wonder if this rings a bell for anyone.  Thank you.

Comment: I think that originally Tarski proved this before he was familiar with Godel numbering, so there should be a proof without them. I'm not sure how he did that, though.

Comment: How can you even state Tarski's theorem without using Godel numbering?

Comment: But there are way to prove Godel's theorem without *diagonalization* (see Peter Smith's paper : *Kleene's proof of Godel's Theorem*).

Comment: @Yuval good point!  Maybe i just meant without the diagonalization lemma.

Comment: I suppose that you can see : R.Smullyan, *Diagonalization and Self-Reference* (1994), Ch.5, para.2: Tarski's method of achieving self-reference. See page 75 : "self-reference can be achieved by Godel's method of diagonalization (which involves substitution), or by a simpler method due to Alfred Tarski".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you, I will see if I can find that book.